# How to nest promises and catch error in outer promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am writing a unit test to ensure that catch works in the following function:

```
function myFunction(){
const myPromises = Promise.all(getMyPromises())

return Promise.all(myPromises
      .then( objArray => {
      return Promise.all(Promise.map(objArray,
    doSomethingWithPromises()
        )).then(response =>  {
            getSomeMorePromises()
             return response;
        })
        .catch(err => {
                  doSomethingWhenErr();
                });
      })
)      .catch(err => {
doSomethingWhenErr(); 
 });
```

}

I am unable to catch the error from the inner catch in the outer therefor my unit test is failing.

I have tried excluding the catch from the inner function however that didn't work.

How do I ensure that if a promise is not resolved in  the getSomeMorePromises() the error is  returned and catched in the outer?

Comment: Your `catch()` callbacks are all completely useless.  Delete them.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's quite unreadable.

Comment: Your usages of `Promise.all` and `Promise.map` seem really misguided.

Comment: Slaks - I need to do something when there is an error. I edited the question

Comment: At Bergi - I asked for help not your criticism. That doesnt help me resolve the problem,

Comment: @user1526912 If you want our help, please format the code so that we can understand it. Help us to help you :-) And I just wanted to point out another problem you have, which I however cannot resolve without knowing what [your code is supposed to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @Bergi - I understand that  well formatted code would make my question more understandable ."Your usages of Promise.all and Promise.map seam really misguided". When someone ask a question most times they are likely misguided explaining why they asked the question in the first place. Your last comment is totally unnecessary

Comment: @user1526912 OK, let me formulate it as a question: What did you intend those calls to do? What are `getMyPromises()` and `doSomethingWithPromises()` doing, can you post their implementation? However, these problems don't have anything to do with your forgotten `return` and the unhandled `getSomeMorePromises()` rejections that you asked about.

Comment: "That doesnt help me resolve the problem"? Not all questions need an answer to be solved. *Some* need not to exist in the first place.

Comment: Way too confusing code to have any idea what you are trying to accomplish.  When we don't know what you are trying to accomplish, we can't really provide you code that would do that.

Answer (score 1):

Promise chains are formed from promises *that you return* from your `then()` callbacks.

Merely creating a promise inside a `then()` callback doesn't link to it or handle its errors in any way.

You need to return those promises:

```
function myFunction() {
    const myPromises = Promise.all(getMyPromises())

    return myPromises.then(objArray => {
        return Promise.all(objArray.map(getOtherPromise));
    )).then(response => {
        return Promise.all(getSomeMorePromises());
    });
}
```